# How can I create sum of previous days?

Tags: r

I have this df with column t. I want to create columns t-1 and t-2 where t-1 gives the sum of two days and t-2 gives the sum of three days.

```
  year      t  t-1 t-2
19620101    1   NA  NA
19630102    2   3   NA
19640103    3   5   6
19650104    4   7   9
19650104    5   9   12
19650104    6   11  15
```

How can I do this?

Extra question:

Can I do this automatically where I mention acc=3 and the code creates two columns with names (t-1),(t-2) or t1,t2 etc? Because my accumulations vary a lot, having an automatic solution help me a great deal. Thanks!'

**Expected Output #2**

```
 year      t  t-1 t-2
19620101    1   NA  NA
19630102    2   NA   NA
19640103    3   3   NA
19650104    4   5   6
19650104    5   7   9
19650104    6   9  12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you already working with `data.table`, so you could easily combine it with `zoo::rollsum` while setting whatever index you want. For example:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
indx <- 2:5 
setDT(df1)[, paste0("t", indx - 1L) := 
             lapply(indx, function(x) rollsum(t, x,
                             na.pad = TRUE, align='right'))]
df1
#        year t t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1: 19620101 1 NA NA NA NA
# 2: 19630102 2  3 NA NA NA
# 3: 19640103 3  5  6 NA NA
# 4: 19650104 4  7  9 10 NA
# 5: 19650104 5  9 12 14 15
# 6: 19650104 6 11 15 18 20
```

Or with `base R/zoo`

```
df1[paste0('t', indx - 1L)] <- lapply(indx, function(x) rollsum(df1$t,
                                   x, na.pad= TRUE, align='right'))
df1
#       year t t1 t2 t3 t4
# 1 19620101 1 NA NA NA NA
# 2 19630102 2  3 NA NA NA
# 3 19640103 3  5  6 NA NA
# 4 19650104 4  7  9 10 NA
# 5 19650104 5  9 12 14 15
# 6 19650104 6 11 15 18 20
```

Or using only `base R` functions

```
 df1[paste0('t', indx - 1L)] <-  lapply(indx, function(x) 
                     as.vector(stats::filter(df1$t, rep(1,x), sides=1)))
```

#### Update

Based on the new output, we can use the devel version of `data.table`, which has `shift` with `type` options for `lead` or `lag`.  The default is `lag`

```
indx <- 2:3
setDT(df1)[, paste0('t', indx - 1L) := lapply(indx, function(x) 
         shift(rollsum(t,x, na.pad=TRUE, align='right')))]
#      year t t1 t2
#1: 19620101 1 NA NA
#2: 19630102 2 NA NA
#3: 19640103 3  3 NA
#4: 19650104 4  5  6
#5: 19650104 5  7  9
#6: 19650104 6  9 12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(year = c(19620101L, 19630102L, 19640103L, 
19650104L, 
19650104L, 19650104L), t = 1:6), .Names = c("year", "t"),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you. I am testing it. Is there a "quicker" way to do it where I mention acc=5 and it automatically creates 5 columns? Previously, I used something like this to create lagged columns (no sum): 

setDT(dfcal)[, paste(model,sep='_',1:lag) := shift(dfcal[[model]], 1:lag)]

Comment: I would prefer not to mention t1, t2 myself. Instead if the code could make it t-1,t-2 or t1, t2 automatically, it would be great. The reason is sometimes I may have to create 20 day rollsums and it changes a lot for my work.

Comment: @maximusdooku for the `rollsum`, the `k` can be only a single element.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Can you post that as a solution as it is totally different

Comment: No, it is your solution basically. You can post it. I also wonder why did you decide to use `dplyr` here anyway. Don't see any use for it in your answer. You probably could just use `transform` from base R instead.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Initially, I was playing around with `shift`, but couldn't get it right, then I went for dplyr so that I can keep working on the data.table for a better solution.

Comment: Why would you use `shift` here?

Comment: @DavidArenburg  I was thinking that I may not need `rollsum`, but could come up with the solution using a combination of `cumsum`, diff, and shift, etc, it didn't work out.

Comment: Awesome. @DavidArenburg's code works perfectly. Just one thing: I am working in Rstudio. And when I open the dataframe, I can see the new columns, but the display itself doesn't update with the new number of columns. It just shows as x obs. of 1 variable. Even though now there are 5 variables. I restarted Rstudio to check but it persists. Never seen this before

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What `data.table` version you have? Maybe update both `data.table` and Rstudio.

Comment: @maximusdooku Please check the `str(yourdata)`

Comment: Nice, I never fully understood how filter works really.

Comment: @DavidArenburg By default, I think the `method=convoluted`, based on the documentation `If ‘"convolution"’ a moving average is used`

Comment: @ akrun @DavidArenburg Could you please tell me how can I modify this code if I want to ignore the value at the current time step when I do accumulations? I have put Expected Output #2 in the question.....