# How can I create sum of previous days but ignore the value at time t?

Tags: r

I have this df with column t. I want to create columns t2 and t3 where

- t2 gives the sum of t-2 and t-3
- t3 gives the sum of t-2, t-3 and t-4 etc.

This is the dataframe

```
year      t    t2   t3
19620101    1   NA  NA
19630102    2   NA  NA
19640103    3   3   NA
19650104    4   5   6
19650104    5   7   9
19650104    6   9   12
```

A slightly different version of this question is here: [How can I create sum of previous days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756924/how-can-i-create-sum-of-previous-days/29757013#29757013)

Basically I don't want to use the value at time t in accumulation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `roll` function in terms of zoo's `rollapplyr` and use it.  Note that the `rollapplyr` `width` argument `list(-seq(k))` means use the indicated offsets.  For example, if k = 2 then it equals `list(c(-1, -2))` which means use the values one and two prior.

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(t, k) rollapplyr(t, list(-seq(k)), sum, fill = NA)
transform(df, t2 = roll(t, 2), t3 = roll(t, 3))
```

An alternative would be this:

```
roll <- function(t, k) rollsumr(t, k+1, fill = NA) - t
```

giving:

```
      year t t2 t3
1 19620101 1 NA NA
2 19630102 2 NA NA
3 19640103 3  3 NA
4 19650104 4  5  6
5 19650104 5  7  9
6 19650104 6  9 12
```

**Note:** We used this as `df`:

```
df <-
structure(list(year = c(19620101L, 19630102L, 19640103L, 19650104L, 
19650104L, 19650104L), t = 1:6), .Names = c("year", "t"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible to automate it ? Where I can mention a value and it automatically creates that many columns

Comment: Try: `do.call(cbind, lapply(2:k, roll, t = df$t))`

Comment: So I should use this way? roll <- function(t, k)  function(t, k) rollsumr(t, k+1, fill = NA) - t; do.call(cbind, lapply(2:k, roll, t = df$t)) . Sorry I am not very proficient with complicated code in R. Specially the apply functions.

Comment: Have fixed the second roll definition.  You can use either one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "I don't want to use the value at time t in accumulation". What about the following?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(t2 = lag(t,1) + lag(t,2), t3 = lag(t,1) + lag(t,2) + lag(t,3))
     date t t2 t3
1 1-01-20 1 NA NA
2 1-01-21 2 NA NA
3 1-01-22 3  3 NA
4 1-01-23 4  5  6
5 1-01-24 5  7  9
6 1-01-25 6  9 12
```

Comment: Hi, this is working. I actually know how to do it "manually". But wanted an automated solution similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29757013/3942806

I would like to give it a value based on which it creates n columns. By not using t accumulation, I meant the first column should add the previous two days of data and not today+yesterday as given in my linked answer. Please let me know if I need to clarify further.

Comment: What about solving this with a self-written function?